# How to save text in variable and print it afterwards?

Tags: variable

I would like to create a command that: when an argument is given, it saves it "somewhere", and when no argument is given, it prints all saved arguments. Something like this:

```
\example{text1}
\example{text2}
\example{text3}
```

(not output)

```
\example
```

Output: text1,text2,text3

If this is not possible with the same command, there could be 2 different commands. I guess this is possible since some templates print the information of "\author" when calling \maketitle.

Answer (score 2):

I'd not use the same command with two different purposes.

```
\documentclass{article}

%\usepackage{xparse} % uncomment for LaTeX prior to 2020-10-01

\ExplSyntaxOn
\seq_new:N \g_kuonb_example_seq

\NewDocumentCommand{\example}{m}
 {
  \seq_gput_right:Nn \g_kuonb_example_seq { #1 }
 }

\NewDocumentCommand{\printexample}{+O{,~}}
 {
  \seq_use:Nn \g_kuonb_example_seq { #1 }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\example{text1}
\example{text2}
\example{text3}

\begin{document}

\printexample

\printexample[\par]

\end{document}
```

The optional argument to `\printexample` is what is set between any two items.

This could be extended if you give more details about the intended working.

[image]